# Assigning same values to a specific cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with column 1 containing alphabets and the other three columns should have values. Every alphabet has a unique value i.e. in column 1 if there are 10 A, for example, then all the "A's" will have the same value. I tried to assign the values by using the chained indexing, but then I have to assign the values for all the cells. In case if I have a large number of rows, then how will the chain indexing work? I know chain indexing won't take into account to iterate over my CSV to assign, let say, a value of 10 to all "A".

Right now my data looks like this:

I want to assign, let say, a value of 5 in "in1" to all "L", but I guess chain indexing won't work here. Is there any alternate solution?

[image]

Comment: access group of rows and assign a value .
df.loc[df['alph'].isin(['L']), 'in1'] = 5

Answer (score 1):

df

```
    alpha   in1 in2 in3
0   M           
1   F           
2   V           
3   F           
4   L           
5   V           
6   L           
7   L           
8   P           
9   L           
10  V
```

df['in1'] = np.where(df['alpha']=='L',5,'')

```
    alpha   in1 in2 in3
0   M           
1   F           
2   V           
3   F           
4   L       5       
5   V           
6   L       5       
7   L       5       
8   P           
9   L       5       
10  V
```